# Combined to views into the one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using scaffolding and I was wanting to no what is the best way to load  a List into my model for example I am wanting the create page to be the same as edit page so I need some way to when i go to the edit action to bring in the product images. I am using asp.net core if that makes a difference.

For Example

My product model will contain .

```
public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public List<ProductImages> ProductImages { get; set; }
}
```

What i am wanting to no what would my best way on edit would be to detect if the user want to create or edit a record a present scafollidng has created these two methods.

```
// POST: Products/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ProductId,ProductName,LongDescription,ShotDescription,OldPrice,NewPrice,DisableBuyButton,DisableWishListButton,ShowForPrice,NotReturnable,MinimumCartQty,MaximumCartQty,SKU,ShippingEnabled,Weight,Length,Width,Height,Categories,ManufacturerPartNumber,AvailableDate,AvailableEndDate,AdminComment,CreatedOn,UpdatedOn,DisplayAvailability,ExpectedDateBackOnStock,IsOnBackOrder,Warehouse,BinNumber,IlseNumber,IsGiftCard,IsDownloadableProduct,IsRental,SeoDescription,Stock,PropertyImageId")] Products products)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {


                products.UserId =  new Guid(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                _context.Add(products);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(products);
        }

        // GET: Products/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var products = await _context.Products.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ProductId == id);
            if (products == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(products);
        }
```

Before in webforms this would have been easy I would have just checked a parameter on the form load but how do I achieve the same in mvc, And how would i redirect my controller to use the one view. Instead of two single files for create.cshtml and edit.cshtml.

Ps is there any better scaffolding add on out that that produce more comptablle html with bootstrap ?.

Also is it good practise to combined the create and edit cause they basically do the same function I dont want to have to do this for all the views I create.

Comment: Check the Id(ProductId) value and determine based on that. If null means, It is for creating new, else edit

Comment: But how do i deal with that should I just create a new Action in that way cause how would i deal with the line

Answer (score 0):

i think we don't have scaffolding templates to generate code for this scenario...but you change your action methods like this..

```
// this method is to recieve first request and also edit request..  
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int id)
        {
          Products products = new Products();
          if(id == 0) //here you can write create part
           {
              // code to bind something..
           }
          else //in else you can write edit part
           {
              products = GetProductById(id); // this is to get edit data..
           }

         return View(products);
        }
    // this post method will recieve data while creating and updating.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Products products)
        {
         if(products.ProductId == 0) 
           {
              CreateProduct(products); // record insertion procedure
           }
          else 
           {
              UpdateProduct(products); // record update procedure
           }
        }
```

and here we use only one view(Create.cshtml) for create and edit..
and do not forgot to keep ProductId in the view, this ProductId will have value 0 while creating record and it will have 1 or 2..etc (id value) while updating

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductId)
```

this way you can create ,edit and update with two action methods & one view....